# How to calculate the discount using javascript in laravel

Tags: laravel

I wanna calculate the discount using javascript but cannot get the right thing. I tried to do something. Here is my code. Take a look :)

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('discount_percent', 'Discount Percent', ['class'=>'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::number('discount_percent', null, ['class'=>'form-control discount']) !!}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('total_fee', 'Total Fee', ['class'=>'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::text('total_fee', null, ['class'=>'form-control final_fee', 'readonly', 'name'=>'final_fee', 'id'=>'final_fee']) !!}
                </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.val').keyup(function () {
                var Fee = parseInt($('.final_fee').val());
                var discount = parseInt($('.discount').val());
                var FinalFee = Fee - ( Fee * discount / 100);
                $('#final_fee').val(FinalFee);
            });
```

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193158/laravel-issues

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state what the error was.  I can guess that nothing is happening, which is probably because you are not binding to your inputs.  If you are hoping to trap *either* input, and then recalc based on the values within, bind the keyup to both of the inputs:

```
$('.discount, .final_fee').keyup(function () { ... }
```

A second problem might be that you are pulling a class for your element for the variables.  I don't know what your full form looks like, but it may help you to label the elements you want to pull Fee and discount from using an id rather than a class.  Remember to add the `#discount` in the form (you already have the `#final_fee`)  So, it would perhaps help to rewrite the method like this:

```
$('#discount, #final_fee').keyup(function () {
     var Fee = parseInt($('#final_fee').val());
     var discount = parseInt($('#discount').val());
     var FinalFee = Fee - ( Fee * discount / 100);
     $('#final_fee').val(FinalFee);
 });
```

This should get you most of the way there.

Comment: There is not any error actually but i just write that code and its not working. giving me nothing. and  i also tried your code. i have the same result